# How to handle onClick in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let customStyle = {
  color: "red",
  fontSize: "20px",
  border: "1px solid black"
};

var colorChange = function () {
  customStyle.color = "blue";
  customStyle.fontSize = "30px";
  customStyle.border = "1px solid black";
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1 style={customStyle}>Hello World!</h1>
      <button onClick={colorChange}> Click Me </button>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1 style={customStyle}>Hello World!</h1>
    <button onClick={colorChange}> Click Me </button>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I want the text to change color on clicking the button. But unable to do so. I console logged the object customStyle inside the function colorChange, but it wouldn't change value to the properties. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is a very strange way of using React.  Shouldn't you be creating components and updating their state, not calling `ReactDOM.render()` multiple times?  It honestly looks like you need to start with some introductory React tutorials, a single Stack Overflow question probably isn't enough to get started here.

Comment: I just started learning React. Like yesterday. So I was just playing around

Comment: @Tommy : No problem. Learn step by step ;) For ReactJS, you should learn ES6 concepts like spread operator, de-structuring, array methods map,filter etc  ... Thiese concepts are used quite often :) Enjoy Coding. React is Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily like the following. Check out [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2y1jd6?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
// App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState({
    color: "red",
    fontSize: "20px",
    border: "1px solid black"
  })

  const colorChange = () => {
    setStyles({
      color: "blue",
      fontSize: "30px",
      border: "1px solid black"
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={styles}>Hello World!</h1>
      <button onClick={colorChange}> Click Me </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// main.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a `Component` and render into `ReactDOM.render()`. Your code needs lots of modifications to follow component approach and state based approach. Here is what your can try this in your `index.js` file in the project created by `npx create-react-app`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


let customStyle = {
  color: "red",
  fontSize: "20px",
  border: "1px solid black",
};

 /*--- Here I am creating my Test component --- */
const Test = () => {
  const [myStyles, setMyStyles] = useState(customStyle);

  /* --- Handler --- */
  const colorChange = () => {
    setMyStyles({
      ...myStyles,
      color: "blue",
      fontSize: "30px",
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={myStyles}>Hello World!</h1>
      <button onClick={colorChange}> Click Me </button>
    </div>
  );
};
/* --- Component code ended ---*/
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Test />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

strange code for me. But i'll try to help. I think this is what you want.
your approach is very incorrect I think. Try this one. or you can use another approach like the way of @Imran Rafiq Rather

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [change, setChange] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange = () => {
    setChange((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const Style = {
    color: !change ? "red" : "blue",
    fontSize: "20px",
    border: "1px solid black"
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={Style}>Hello World!</h1>
      <button onClick={handleChange}> Click Me </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```